# Draw new things below old things in PIXI.js w. WebGL

Tags: canvas, webgl, pixi.js

I'm working on a bullet hell in PIXI.js. For the visual style that I'm going for, new bullets need to be drawn beneath old ones. It seems that the default rendering places new objects above old ones.

Using the 2d canvas context, I know how to do this: `composite-operation: destination-over`. But this API doesn't seem to exist for WebGL.

Reading through the PIXI.js GitHub, I see there are issues related to sorting the children of the stage to determine rendering order. Although this may work for small numbers of things, I plan to be rendering tons and tons of bullets (on the order of 10k). I worry that manual sorting might slow down the game on slower computers.

I'd love if there was a way to adjust how new shapes are drawn using PIXI's API, similar to setting `composite-operation`.

I also dug through the API docs for Pixi (looking through everything related to the Renderers), and nothing stood out as the answer.

Do you know of any way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: If you havent yet, I suggest posting the question in: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/15-pixijs/. Stackoverflow is quite silent regarding pixi. Unfortunately i dont have an answer fof you and i suspect there isnt an easy way out of this. Unless someone else has already done the exact same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, @hachi! I'll do that.